# Display rows to column without an aggregate function

Tags: sql, presto

I have data like this

```
type reg     met
AAC  AP     5.849357195
SAC  EM     0.8690077048
SAC  AP     0.537474743
AAC  EM     3.118546972
AAC  La     7.385316518
```

I want to display it as below using SQL or presto

```
type    AP              EM         La
AAC  5.849357195    3.118546972 7.385316518
SAC  0.537474743    0.8690077048    -
```

pivot doesn't seem to fit my use case bcoz there should be an aggregate in the pivot.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select type,
       max(case when reg = 'AP' then met end) as ap,
       max(case when reg = 'EM' then met end) as em,
       max(case when reg = 'LA' then met end) as la
from t
group by type;
```

Note that you could also use `pivot` with `max()`.  I recommend conditional aggregation instead.  It is standard SQL, much more flexible, and as far as I know, there is no performance advantage to using `pivot`.